# Cuda NVCC compiler - how to /showincludes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, nvcc

I need to show all the includes (in the order they are included) in the Output window of Visual Studio to find out which file produced some obscure error.

But can't find a way to enable "/showincludes" when compiling a project in Visual Studio for Cuda. It uses NVCC, which seems to lack this option.

There is an option in ProjectSettings -> C/C++ -> Advanced ->Show all includes.

However, this option is missing in ProjectSettings -> Cuda C/C++"

Is there a way to enable it?

I found [a similar post from 2018](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044902/cuda-programming-and-performance/nvcc-output-include-files/)  but it has no answer.

Answer (score 2):

nvcc supports the [`-M`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-specifying-compilation-phase-generate-dependencies) and [`-MM`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-specifying-compilation-phase-generate-nonsystem-dependencies) options which, when no [dependency output file](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications-dependency-output) is specified, will print the includes to stdout.

<s>The Visual Studio integration doesn't really have a switch for that, but you should be able to specify it in the Additional Options in the Command Line category of the CUDA C/C++ project properties…</s>

Comment: Hm, tossing `-M` into `Cuda C/C++ -> Command Line ->Additional Options` causes the following error: `nvcc fatal   : More than one compilation phase specified`.  Using `-M  -MM` makes it produce `nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'MM'`

Comment: @Kari indeed, I forgot that that's treated as a separate phase and, thus, will probably mess with the VS integration. I'm afraid you'd have to call nvcc yourself then, e.g., on the developer command prompt…

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any compiler flag through to the underlying host compiler via [`-Xcompiler <flag>`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-passing-specific-phase-options-compiler-options).
Thus `-Xcompiler /showincludes` should do.

Comment: Tried putting `-Xcompiler "/showincludes    " ` into `Cuda C/C++ -> Command Line ->Additional Options` but the output window just keeps showing the files one by one.  Some time afterwards, it starts giving these errors: `2>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/showincludes'`.  Using Visual Studio 2017 btw

Comment: Note that this will just pass `/showincludes` to the host compiler. This won't work if the host compiler is not used or if the includes differ between host and device code…